# multiple divs not expanding to adjust to dynamic content IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've been struggling with this CSS problem for a while and no answers online seem to be working for me (I've spent the past few days reading so many posts).

The problem I"m having is that there are three divs wrapping dynamic content, and as the content grows (the content is hidden at the beginning and then shown with Jquery by clicking on the titles for each section growing) the divs do not expand correctly like they do in every other browser (including FF 3.0).

I've tried min-height, overflow:auto, overflow:hidden, height:100%, everything. With overflow:auto, I get scroll bars and only one of the divs adjusting properly inside the scroll bars. With overflow:hidden the content is just hidden, duh hah. And then min-height and height have done nothing but letting the content spill out.

Here is the CSS for the three divs:

```
// outher div, it's floating left next to a leftbar
div#conwrap {
  background: #C0E7F4;
  width: 810px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

/* For 2 column layout */
div#main_wide {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

// Inner div. The main one I want to expand.
div.round {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:15px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:15px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0px 0;
}
```

And then the html for the content inside of the div.round:

```
/* Block for education details */
<h3 class="edit_type" id="education">Education</h3> 
<ul>...</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

/* Block for account details */  
<h3 class="edit_type" id="account">Account</h3>
<ul>...</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And so on ... (there are three more blocks)

Using Jquery, all the uls are hidden at the beginning and then shown or hidden when you click on the h3.

Any help??
Thanks so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sepecify `height:auto;` to the inner div that might help.

Comment: Can you post the content inside ul?

Comment: Sure! This is for instance what the "account" block has:

    <li>
      <label for="schoolemail">Preferred Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
      {{ profile.preferred_email }}
      <a>Change email</a>{{ profile_edit_form.email_private }} Keep private
      <span id="miniclarify2"> to sign in and receive notifications </span>
    </li>